# How can I debug java.sql.SQLException: could not resolve the connect identifier

Tags: java, oracle, exception, connection

I'm getting the error message "java.sql.SQLException: could not resolve the connect identifier", but it isn't consistently failing, sometimes it works.

In the application, a connectivity check is being run, either scheduled with quartz scheduler, or with a button to run it immediately.

The run immediately usually works, while the scheduled running fails most of the time.
Do you have a suggestion how I can debug this?

The lastest change to the system was changing the tnsnames.ora.
The new tnsnames.ora has 4 server IPs in an ADDRESS_LIST, while the old tnsnames.ora had just three.

The code is:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(timeoutSeconds);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, decryptedPassword);
conn.close();
```

Comment: `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` what do you expect this to do, by itself?

Comment: This loads the oracle jdbc driver.

Comment: No, it *returns* the class for the jdbc driver. But you do nothing with the result.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it's the ancient way of getting drivers to register themselves. Loading them with `forName` calls their static initializer with the registration code. This is not needed anymore but it still shows up in many jdbc tutorials. That is not the explanation for the exception though.

Comment: @Jesper yeah, I read the documentation a bit more thoroughly (only the 3-parameters version specifies that initialization is performed) and indeed this is the case. You always learn something.

Comment: @f1sh indeed. Yes, I was not pointing to it as a possible cause, I was just wondering what it was doing there by itself.

Comment: What is your connection URL? Are you actually using a tnsnames.ora alias? The error "could not resolve the connect identifier" implies that it isn't finding the connect string in tnsnames.ora at all. please post the content of your URL, the sqlnet.ora, and the tnsnames.ora (with IPs masked appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that another developer was running his own tomcat locally using the same database as the tomcat that is supposed to work on the database.

On his local machine, the tnsnames.ora did not contain the remote databases being checked, thus leading to the error message.